# Tracking order of calls with autospeced mocks

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I'm experiencing some bizarre problems with the `unittest.mock` module in Python 3.6.

In my tests, I'm attaching mocks to a parent mock in order to be able to track the order in which they are called.

Here's a toy example to illustrate the issue:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock


def add(a, b):
    return a + b


def div(a, b):
    return a / b


def add_plus_div(a, b):
    return [add(a, b), div(a, b)]


@mock.patch("__main__.add")
@mock.patch("__main__.div")
class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_one(self, mock_div, mock_add):

        parent = mock.Mock()
        parent.attach_mock(mock_div, "div")
        parent.attach_mock(mock_add, "add")

        add_plus_div(1, 2)

        parent.assert_has_calls([
            mock.call.add(1, 2),
            mock.call.div(1, 2),
        ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This works fine, and passes as you would expect.

However, if you autospec the mocks:

```
@mock.patch("__main__.add", autospec=True)
@mock.patch("__main__.div", autospec=True)
class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_one(self, mock_div, mock_add):

        parent = mock.Mock()
        parent.attach_mock(mock_div, "div")
        parent.attach_mock(mock_add, "add")

        add_plus_div(1, 2)

        parent.assert_has_calls([
            mock.call.add(1, 2),
            mock.call.div(1, 2),
        ])
```

You get a failure:

```
AssertionError: Calls not found.
Expected: [call.add(1, 2), call.div(1, 2)]
Actual: []
```

Does anyone know why autospecing breaks things, and how I can track the call order of a number of autospeced mocked functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is an instance of a known, but long-standing bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue21478